# PHP 5.5.9 with Apache 2.2 on Windows

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php

Is it possible to run PHP 5.5.9 with Apache 2.2 on Windows? The PHP 5.5.9 package only comes with the `php5apache2_4.dll` module, which clearly doesn't work with Apache 2.2. I'm having trouble finding a module through search.

Comment: Same problem here. Really bugs me out. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I second that question...

Comment: Checkout http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/downloads it comes with PHP 5.5.13. There's a free edition.